# What do the numeric arguments for meta_predicate mean in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: module, prolog, meta-predicate

I am writing a Prolog program, and I am trying to incorporate modules into the program design to encapsulate complexity reduce redundant functionality.

One feature I am having difficulty with is the use of metapredicates.  I would like to define a metapredicate in one module and then import it into a different module; this introduces complications.  Fortunately, the `meta_predicate` directive helps resolve module prefixes, but I am having trouble understanding the arguments as described here: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=metapred

Specifically, I am having trouble with the numeric arguments.  As per the documentation:

> The argument is a term that is used to reference a predicate with N more arguments than the given argument term. For example: call(0) or maplist(1, +).

I understand that an argument denoted by the numeric value will be a term that is used to reference a predicate.  What I do not understand is how the referenced predicate could have more arguments than the argument term.  Can someone offer a more in-depth explanation of when the numeric argument is appropriate, or an example of when it would be appropriate to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a formulation that is easy to understand only when one knows what it means, and should probably be redone.

```
:-meta_predicate maplist(2, ?, ?).
```

... just means that the argument on the place of the "2" will be used as the kernel of a predicate that will be called. We have no special notation for that (a big mistake IMHO), so we will write it in standard fashion as a term like `f(foo,bar)`, or `f(foo)`, or `f`. What will the meta-predicate `maplist/3` do with that term? Well, it will syntactically transform it and tack "2" additional arguments on its end (and only on its end, which results in awkwardness): `f(foo,bar, ARG1,ARG2)`, or `f(foo, ARG1,ARG2)`, or `f(ARG1,ARG2)`. *Then* `maplist/3` will call it.

For example, for the aforementioned `maplist/3`, take this predicate taking two arguments:

```
myprint(X,Y) 
   :- format("~w\n",[(X,Y)]).
```

It can be used in a `maplist/3` call like this, not indicating any args:

```
maplist(myprint,[0,1,2,3],[a,b,c,d]).
```

and two arguments, one from each list, will be tacked on the term `myprint` before that term is knighted to become a predicate, and called:

```
?- maplist(myprint,[0,1,2,3],[a,b,c,d]).
0,a
1,b
2,c
3,d
true.
```

This allows one to pass "partially filled-in calls". `maplist/2` will tack 1 argument to the end of its first argument, so one can say:

```
?- maplist(myprint("foo+"),[a,b,c,d]).
foo+,a
foo+,b
foo+,c
foo+,d
true.
```

The above become actually usable in combination with Paulo Moura's [`library(yall)`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall), which wraps a goal into an anonymous predicate, exposing the arguments. Then one can flexibly rearrange things

```
?- maplist([X,Y]>>format("~w\n",[(X,Y)]),[0,1,2,3],[a,b,c,d]).
0,a
1,b
2,c
3,d
true.
```

```
?- maplist([Y,X]>>format("~w\n",[(X,Y)]),[0,1,2,3],[a,b,c,d]).
a,0
b,1
c,2
d,3
true.
```

In fact `library(yall)` provides proper syntax for Lambda expressions that is cruelly missing from the ISO standard, to explicitly show the missing parameters.

One could have imagined to have expressions like these long ago:

```
?- maplist(λX.verify(3,X), [1,2,3,4,5]).
```

or to stay in ASCIIland, something like:

```
?- maplist(\X.verify(3,X), [1,2,3,4,5]).
```

but it didn't happen.

Comment: ... or `?- maplist(\X^verify(3,X), [1,2,3,4,5])` using `library(lambda)` which just stays within ISO.

Comment: ... *but it didn't happen*. Rather you did not read it. See for example, Mycroft & O'Keefe, A Polymorphic Type System for Prolog. Artificial Intelligence 23 (1984) p. 306

Comment: @false I have to admit I haven't looked at `library(lambda)` yet. But there should just have been a placeholder notation. It's weird that it was missed.

Comment: Just the step to include call/N alone was a big effort.

Answer (score 3):

The meta-predicate directive specifies the number of arguments to add to the predicate when calling. Here's a simple example:

```
:- meta_predicate foo(2, +).

foo(Pred, X) :-
    call(Pred, X, Y),
    format('~q(~q,~q)~n', [Pred, X, Y]).

some_pred(X, Y) :-
    Y is X + 1.
```

which produces the following result. As you can see, the `meta_predicate` directive results in the `Pred` argument getting the module added (in this case, `user`):

```
?- foo(some_pred, 5).
user:some_pred(5,6)
```

Something that's similar to a "closure" in other languages can be easily done, also using the meta_predicate directive. For example, we could have

```
:-meta_predicate foo2(1). 

foo2(Pred):-
    call(Pred, Y),
    format('~q=~q',[Pred,Y]).
```

and call it:

```
?-foo2(some_pred(5)).
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  This answered my question and had the further benefit of being very concise.